# Kakfa broker unreachble to RD Kafka Client

Tags: c, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am using RD Kafka C based Client to consume/produce messages to Kafka Broker.
It was working fine for quite sometime but suddenly I am seeing below error:

```
 %3|1540186099.148|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:host1:9092/bootstrap]: host1:9092/bootstrap: Failed to connect to broker at host1:9092: Network is unreachable
    %3|1540186099.148|ERROR|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:host1:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
```

Surprisingly I have seen both Kafka & Zookeeper are running fine.

RD Kafka Client version : 0.11.5
Platform : RHEL 7.2
kafka_2.11-1.1.0
zookeeper-3.4.10

Answer (score 0):

As this was working previously without any errors, I thought of checking the ping to the hoist1 which failed.

```
$ping host1
connect: Network is unreachable
```

This happened because of some network maintenance host1 entry got removed from /etc/hosts.
Once I added it back everything works fine.

Comment: FWIW, "network maintenance" shouldn't be able to modify your local hosts file

Comment: it was by mistake removed from /etc/hosts file.